# Mongoose .update() does nothing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm finding a document called Filter (myFilter=Filter.findById(id)). I update a few fields and then try to update using myFilter.update().
Nothing happens.
What does work is

```
myFilter.New=false; 
myFilter.save()
```

This is fine but randomly causes race condition. Am I using update wrong.

Here's my implementation:

```
    let myFilter = await Filter.findById(myUser.filterID);

    if (!_.isUndefined(distance)) {
      myFilter.searchParams.distance = distance;
    }

    if (!_.isUndefined(distanceMetric)) {
      myFilter.searchParams.distanceMetric = distanceMetric;
    }

    await myFilter.update();
```

Comment: What is your update statement exactly?

Comment: I'll update the question with it. @AliElkhateeb

Comment: I think you’re intending to call `.save()`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating), `Model.update()` should take 2 parameters (`filter` and `doc`).

However, in your case, I suggest you use `myFilter.save()` directly it should work, without the need to set `myFilter.New=false`

Comment: Problem is race-condition. When we save the version will change, causing "No matching document" errors.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using .update() correctly . You need to give _id or some other index of the document as a query and then the data that you want to update.
.save() would be the way to go here.
You can look up update over here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Problem is race-condition. When we save the version will change, causing "No matching document" errors.

Answer (score 0):

I located another question that was similar. Seems the way to go is to use findOneandUpdate :/

But I only want to conditionally set cetain fields as above. If that's not the way to go, let me know please.

This worked for me:

```
    await Filter.findByIdAndUpdate(myUser.filterID, {
      $set: {
        searchParams: {
          ...myFilter.searchParams
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
let searchParams={}

 if (!_.isUndefined(distance)) {
  searchParams.distance = distance;
}

if (!_.isUndefined(distanceMetric)) {
  searchParams.distanceMetric = distanceMetric;
}

await Filter.update({_id: myUser.filterID},{$set:{searchParams}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save changes you have made to a document after loading it with `findOne()` or `findById()`, use `save()`. For example:

```js
const myFilter = await Filter.findById(myUser.filterID);

if (!_.isUndefined(distance)) {
  myFilter.searchParams.distance = distance;
}

if (!_.isUndefined(distanceMetric)) {
  myFilter.searchParams.distanceMetric = distanceMetric;
}

await myFilter.save();
```